# How to disable login password

Tags: password

I am the only user on my PC and do not want to enter my password.  How do I disable?  I do not want to enter a password every time my screen saver starts or I install any aps.

Comment: @Gordon, it is really a bad idea to disable the password altogether, see Madmike's answer below on how to disable it for the screen lock. The duplicate linked above will help you stop all passwords but, one of the biggest security advantages in Linux will be bypassed, and anyone, form anywhere can install a program on your computer(this includes viruses).  With the password it is much more difficult to install malware, as the malware cannot get out of you home folder(at least not easily) and wreck your system files without the password.

Comment: To add to TrailRider's points - you're not only unnecessarily exposing yourself to the risks but others too if your system becomes compromised and abused. All at the cost of little convenience. It's a bit like people who don't vaccinate their kids thinking it's only their kids affected. A bit silly, to be diplomatic about it.

Answer (score 5):

You can disable the password lock from the screen saver by opening a terminal and running `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.screensaver lock-enabled false`.

Comment: This didn't work for me on Ubuntu 20.04. This might work: https://askubuntu.com/a/829799/48214

Comment: I agree that this will probably work. But disabling the passowrd for the screensaver is *not" the same thing as disabling the login passwords.

Comment: Great clarification. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Open the terminal window by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run the command:

```
sudo visudo
```

Find the line that says:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL
```

And change it to:

```
%admin ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Save and exit the file

Source: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-disable-password-prompts-in-ubuntu.html

I must warn you though that disabling all security prompts could pose a major security risk and is extremely inadvisable.