# Password set but login without password?

Tags: 16.04, password

I'm on Ubuntu 16.04. Two home accounts were set.

One of them doesn't prompt for a password request at login page even though I have set a password for it. Is that a bug?

Comment: Not if the account belongs to the `nopasswdlogin` group (you can check with `id -nG` from the account in question, or `getent group nopasswdlogin`

Comment: sudo deluser patrik nopasswdlogin, where patrik is the username

Answer (score 10):

You can define an account where a password isn't required to login. Go to `System Settings`, `User Accounts` and call up the user profile. This screen appears:

[image: No Password]

If `Automatic Login` is set `ON` then no password is required to log on.

### Edit 1 - Login without Password

As https://askubuntu.com/users/367990/byte-commander pointed out in comments you can click on a user's password and this screen will appear:

[image: No Password Required]

Click on the `Action` drop down menu and select `Log in without a password`

Comment: You can also click on "Password" and select "Log in without a password". It will display "NONE" in the summary then and you can log in without password. That way you don't get logged in automatically.

Comment: Thanks for answering. And yeah, I selected "Log in without a password" at the beginning. My problem is that the password was set later on and still I didn't require a password to log in an account.

Comment: Unfortunately there exists no Action drop down menu for Ubuntu20

Answer (score 2):

Solved, ahah! 
For some reason I might have put my account into nopasswordlist. Further info:

[How to get Ubuntu to ask for my password at login screen again?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/581848/how-to-get-ubuntu-to-ask-for-my-password-at-login-screen-again)