# Must I always have to sign in, every time I switch on?

Tags: login, password

I just about understand the point of the keyring, and it's fair that every time I install or delete an application I need to verify myself.

But really, why do I need to sign in every time I switch on my PC? I'm the only registered user, there is no guest account, my wife couldn't open anything more tricky than 'Bing', is there a way to disable user sign in?

Apropos of nothing, I installed Ubuntu 18.10 yesterday.

Comment: User sign-in check system settings, guest I think you have to enable it!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Password set but login without password?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/829790/password-set-but-login-without-password) **Edit**: Whoops, I only looked at the answer. The question is totally different.

Comment: You can turn the "automatic login" feature on from Settings > Details > Users. Are you looking for something else?

Comment: Thanks George, that worked a treat (probably, I'll find out after next time the battery dies). WJAndrea, thank you too, will try that, if George's solution doesn't hit the spot. I appreciate you both for taking the time and effort to help. You rock!

Comment: if it is the keyring popup: remove the password and save it without a password next time you are asked.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to turn the auto-login feature on if you want to log in to your system without providing the password all the time.

Open the "*Settings*" application and navigate to *Details* > *Users*. You should see an "**automatic login**" option. If the option is greyed out, first click the "*unlock*" button and enter your password. Then toggle on the "automatic login" option. After that you'll be able to log in without typing the password all the time.

If your issue is the keyring pop-up, something similar to this:

[image]

then remove the password and save it without a password next time you are asked.

Comment: I bet he is gettng the keyring popup. That is a different popup.

Comment: @Rinzwind I doubted that too, but then again I couldn't understand clearly what OP is actually looking for, especially [from the initial version](https://askubuntu.com/revisions/1088056/1) which is a bit 'noisy'. The title somehow implies login password to me ("MUST I always have to sign in, everytime I *switch on*?'). Also there is this "single user/no guest account" part and OP found George's suggestion to enable guest account to bypass login  helpful. Since OP didn't reply to any of our comments, I thought I would convert my comment to answer for future (other option was VTC as unclear).

Comment: @Rinzwind I think it would be better if you could convert your comment to an answer too to cover both the ends! :-D

Comment: Nope. You started the answer. You add to it >:) https://superuser.com/questions/381428/why-am-i-always-asked-to-unlock-my-login-keyring-at-startup